# Estou com um problema onde realmente eu não sei como fazer um evento que escute uma ação no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3

Tenho um slide show de imagens onde aparece as imagens cadastradas no banco. A tabela se chama **eventos**. Nessa tabela tem um campo chamado de **data_fim**, que seria referente ao final da data do evento, e também tenho um campo chamado **status**, onde ele e do tipo **boolean** que quando ela esta como **true** ela esta ativa no slide. O que preciso para que um serviço escute, que, quando a data atual (date('d')) não for mais a igual a data do campo **data_fim** que ele seja desativada o campo status == false. Como faria para realizar essa façanha?
Estava fazendo assim veja:

```
$evento = Evento::whereDay('data_fim', '<='  ,date('d'))->first();
    if($evento){
         $evento->status = false;
         $evento->save();
    }
```

Mais eu acho que isso é muito gambiarra. Existe uma forma mais inteligente para fazer o mesmo. Gostaria de aprender com serviços no Laravel. Não sei muito bem. Peço que vocês me oriente.

Comment: Você quer verificar sempre antes de salvar?

Comment: Não quero que quando a data do evento passar da data atual que ele desative um campo da tabela

Comment: Certo, mas **quando**?

Comment: Vamos supor a data do evento e dia 28/09/2017 a dia 30/09/2017
Enta eu tenho 2 campos na tabela eventos data_inicio e data_fim 
quando a data atual Ex que hj e dia 31/09/2017 então o campo status seja desativado automaticamente da tabela eventos.

Comment: Então eu fiz assim. Não sei se isso e gambiarra mais funciona hehehe. Gostaria da sua opinião:
 $expirar = Evento::whereDay('data_fim', '<' ,date('d'))->where('status' , true)->where('expirar', true)->first();

       // dd($expirar);
        if(isset($expirar) and $expirar->count() >= 1 ){
            $expirar->expirar = false;
            $expirar->save();
        }

Answer (score -2):

Uma forma de você fazer isso, é criar uma tarefa agendada usando crontab

Uma formula parecida com essa:

```
10 0 * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Basicamente, a instrução que passo pro servidor, é que ele rode esse script, todos os dias ás 00:10.

Então o que você pode fazer é, criar um script que verifique a **data_fim** e compare com a data atual, e dependendo do resultado, você faz o update do campo **status** na sua tabela **eventos**

Aqui tem mais coisas na documentação: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling

E também tem esse site que ajuda na hora de você montar a task: https://crontab.guru

Comment: um crontab pra permiti exibir uma slideshow? Você tem certeza que este é o problema do autor, como ele disse "evento" no caso se refere a uma tabela no banco e não me parece necessariamente eventos reais.

Comment: Acredito que seja uma das formas de se solucionar o problema dele.
Pelo que entendi, ele precisa verificar se a data atual é menor ou igual a **data_fim** da tabela.
O crontab não é para exibir ou não o slideshow, e sim para atualizar o campo **status** da tabela **eventos**.

Comment: crontab pra uma checagem no banco parece uma volta ao mundo para chegar na esquina, o problema dele é só checar as datas e permitir exibir o slide naquele momento, isso se resolve com o where do proprio Eloquente ou até mesmo com uma `if` básica, usar CRONTAB pra isso é o mesmo que colocar 200 cavalos para puxar um carro que está funcionando, ou seja vai dar mais trabalho e no final vai fazer a mesma coisa que poderia fazer simplesmente dando a partida no carro.

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu a dúvida do autor.
O problema não é apenas exibir, é atualizar o campo **status**.

|

> O que preciso para que um serviço escute, que, quando a data atual (date('d')) não for mais a igual a data do campo data_fim que ele seja desativada o campo status == false

|

**Eu** acredito que usar crontab seja sim uma solução, se vai onerar mais recurso do que precisa, ai depende do que a aplicação dele precisa.